# Referencing a WCF Service in the web.config file via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, web-config

I have an asp.net webforms website and a wcf service. I use jQuery to perform my AJAX operations to/from the WCF service like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "192.168.1.24/ServiceMain.svc/" + serviceName,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{}",
    cache: true,
    success: function (json)
    {
       //Success operation here
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        //Error operation here
    }
});
```

All is fine right now. However, I want to be able to do a testing and production environment, both of which will be hosted on a different server with different IP Addresses.

Clearly, hard-coding the URL to point to the correct WCF service will become a tedious problem if left unchecked. Therefore, I was wondering what was the best approach in retrieving the WCF Service's URL. I thought about using the *web.config* file with something like the following:

`<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SomeWCFKey")%>`

However, I am not sure how to correctly reference the address in my web.config file:

```
<endpoint address="http://192.168.1.24/ServiceMain.svc" 
binding="basicHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceMain" 
contract="ServiceMain.IServiceMain" 
name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceMain" />
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think you are actully want to read endpoint address that you can get by this code

```
private List<string> GetEndpoints() 
{
     var endpointList = new List<string>();
     var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
     var serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
      foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in serviceModel.Client.Endpoints)
     {
         endpointList.Add(endpoint.Address.ToString());
     }
      return endpointList; 
}
```

Here is pont that descirpt mroe in detail : [Getting WCF Bindings and Behaviors from any config source](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/11/getting-wcf-bindings-and-behaviors-from-any-config-source.aspx)

this might also help you : [Programmatically enumerate WCF endpoints defined in app.config](http://mostlytech.blogspot.ca/2007/11/programmatically-enumerate-wcf.html)

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I got it working. Thank you.